# What report format can be used to motivate a young adult to learn about investments?

Tags: united-states, investing

My 21 year old sister has some money coming. I want to show her in a one page report, what the results will be if she invest that money (bonds/stocks/commodities) vs taking the money and not investing it.

It will be nice if that type of calculator/report will also show what will happen with that investment in 10-15 years if she adds to it rather than take from it.

Comment: What about a spreadsheet? You can look up [average returns](http://people.stern.nyu.edu/ADAMODAR/New_Home_Page/datafile/histret.html) of stocks and bonds and use those to calculate future cash flows, values, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have always though that the [Choose to Save](http://www.choosetosave.org/) organization has a lot of good information. Including one on the [magic of compounding](http://www.choosetosave.org/brochures/pdf/ncompnd.pdf)

```
Final Total at Age 65.
$107,209 : Saved $2,000 per year from age 20 to age 30. Save nothing else after age 30.
$251,578 : Saved $2,000 per year from age 20 to age 65.
$152,288 : Saved $2,000 per year from age 30 to age 65.
 $85,688 : Saved $2,000 per year from age 40 to age 65.
 $41,015 : Saved $2,000 per year from age 50 to age 65.
Assumes a 4% annual rate of return compounded monthly.
```

Comment: That site is *much* better than my recommendation to use a spreadsheet.

Comment: 4%? That first line, with 8%, only ten years of saving, $428K by age 65. Or if you are a fan of The David, you can use 12%. Good presentation.